# How create isolated ext4 filesystem on file

Tags: linux, filesystems, mkfs

There is a 25G /dev/sda6 ext4 partition mounted on /data. I'm trying to make a fixed size filesystem on a file using `fallocate`, `mkfs.ext4`, `mount`:

```
fallocate -l 5G /data/new_storage
mkfs.ext4 -E nodiscard /data/new_storage
mkdir /data/new_dir
mount /data/new_storage /data/new_dir
```

However `du` for /data shows that /data/new_storage takes 4.9G instead of 5G. This happens after `mkfs.ext4` is executed. At the same time, `ls` says that the file occupies 5G.

Because of this, the new file system is not isolated, and if, after the creation of the child filesystem, the parent filesystem is completely filled, then filling the child filesystem can lead to errors:

```
loop: Write error at byte offset 2281734144, length 4096.
print_req_error: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 4456512
```

When using ext2, `du` shows exactly as much as was allocated, and there are no errors with similar behavior.

Disabling journal for ext4 shows `du` a little closer to 5G, but still not equal to 5G.

As expected behavior, there is a /dev/sda6 partition that will have 20G of 25G free (slightly less free due to service data), and a second looback /dev/loop0 partition of 5G (slightly less due to service data) isolated from each other. Is it possible to achieve this behavior?

There is also the possibility that `fstrim` will be executed, which will result in holes being punched in the file. Is it possible to somehow completely disable the execution of `fstrim` on a new filesystem.

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent LVM? If /data exists only so you can carve it up into smaller chunks then consider replacing it with a Volume Group and creating Logical Volumes instead of loopback images

Comment: @roaima The disk is already partitioned and I'm in a situation where I'm not allowed to change partitions in any way and there's no way to use LVM. /data should also contain its own files and directories. In fact, I need to reserve space for a directory, and i'm trying to do this using loopback images.

Comment: By default ext4 usually holds back 5% of the filesystem which is reserved for the root user. You can specify not to do this in the mkfs.ext4 command. See the man page for mke2fs. You need the -m option. This may explain the discrepancy

Comment: You really should not remove the 5% reservation for small extN filesystems, @PonJar. Maybe reduce it a little (or a lot for large filesystems) but the efficiency drops off dramatically as the filesystem fills

Comment: @PonJar Unfortunately, this does not help, already tried. There is such strange behavior that on another system, the same set of commands works as expected.

Comment: @roaima I understand the issue for a system disk, however this partition appears to be destined for data storage based on the name of the mount point. For that use case I assume the  reservation is unnecessary. I would like to learn about this if I am wrong.